# String to array (regex, explode or something else)?

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string

What's the easiest way to break a string that's formatted as `"PT2M19S"` or `"PT19S"` (YouTube api video durations) apart so that I end up with an array like so?

```
Array
(
    [M] => 2
    [S] => 19
)
```

Comment: Without seeing said "very odd loop" we'd all have to agree it seems "very awkward".

Comment: You want: *"PT2M19S" or "PT19S"* but what is the actual string?

Comment: What are you going to do with that digits?

Comment: Using this regex would be better : `(?:([0-9]*)+[M])?([0-9]*)[S]` and reading capture groups will give you separated numbers. Now for the loop, I think you have no choice

Comment: @Jay Blanchard - the question isn't about the loop I have already done.  If it was I would have posted it - it's about a simpler, less convoluted way to distribute the string into an array.

Comment: @Andreas - those are the actual strings, I want an array populate by that string as I stated in the question.

Comment: @splash58 - those digits are the length of a video in minutes and seconds in the Youtube api as I stated in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this regexp instead:

```
preg_match_all('/(\d+)([MS])/', $string, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

Then create the associative array using the second capture group as keys and the first group as values.

```
$result = array_combine($matches[2], $matches[1]);
```

Comment: Knew there had to be something better than my awkward solution.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Why not so?

```
$str = 'PT2M19S';
$i = new DateInterval($str);
print_r($i);
```

you can use 'i' and 's' properties of a result object

```
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 0
    [d] => 0
    [h] => 0
    [i] => 2
    [s] => 19
    [weekday] => 0
    [weekday_behavior] => 0
    [first_last_day_of] => 0
    [invert] => 0
    [days] => 
    [special_type] => 0
    [special_amount] => 0
    [have_weekday_relative] => 0
    [have_special_relative] => 0
)
```

Comment: AHHHHH so that's why the YouTube api uses this format, it uses ISO 8601.  I was wondering where they came up with the format. +1 for answering another question for me :)